# Is there a way of being able to solve a captcha in Python MANUALLY

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have started getting into python web automation(with chrome). I am using python 3 and selenium module. Is there a way of having the recaptcha pop up in a seperate window allowing me to solve it like normal and then carrying on with my set automation?
Any advice is much apprectaited
Thanks

[Image of captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrQzI.jpg)

Comment: I don't know how to do it in python but the general idea would be when page loads check for the captcha, get it's position, length, and width. use that to get a screenshot of just the captcha. send it to whatever program you want to show the user. Have a way for the user to enter the solution. Your selenium script should be polling during this time looking for the solution from the user. So if the user types the solution into a console program then the save that to the disk and have selenium keep looking for the saved solution.

Comment: @chris-crush-code. I'm talking about recaptcha v2. I'm not a robot select and manually solving the images. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My instructions are to solve it manually, you want it to pop into a second window and solve, you take a screenshot of the captch and display that in whatever system you want and have a way for the user's solution to get back to the script.

I've personally solved it before by having it pause and wait in the current window with an alert for the user so they just type it in like normal

Comment: @chris-crush-code i added an image to description. I dont see how the user could enter the result when you have to selsct images. It would need to be solved in real time

Comment: ah i see now. if the user has access to the browser you should just have your script prompt them to solve it in the browser window. If they don't have browser access (for example your script is running on a server somewhere) you'll have to get creative, like numbering the pictures in the grid. Eventually it'll give you multiple pages of captchas though so you're best off just having the browser instance run on the users local machine.

Comment: okay. thanks for the suggestions @chris-crush-code

Comment: Or you could request your devs use testable keys in your testing environment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#what-happens-to-recaptcha-v1